# Resouces are undefined for xamarin for Android 8.1

Tags: android, xamarin.android, resources

```
I am using xamarin for the first time, and some resources insists on remaining undefined.

This is the header_layout.xml file:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
    <!-- Hamburger icon -->
    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/hamburger_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/baseline_menu_open_24"
            android:contentDescription="Open Navigation Drawer"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    
    <!-- Add header content -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Header"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />

    <!-- Add more views or controls as needed -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Note the color colorPrimary and the actionBarSize.

These are defined in styles.xml (or at least I thought they were):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
         <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        
    <!-- Change the background color -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>
    <!-- Define the actionBarSize attribute -->
    <item name="android:actionBarSize">@dimen/actionBarSize</item>
    <!-- Define the colorPrimary attribute -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/colorControlNormal</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

And their values as defined in colors.xml and dimens.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#2c3e50</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1B3147</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#3498db</color>
    <color name="colorControlNormal">#555555</color>
    <!-- Define your custom background color -->
    <color name="background_color">#FFA500</color>
</resources>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Define the actionBarSize attribute -->
    <dimen name="actionBarSize">56dp</dimen>
    <!-- You can adjust the value as needed -->
</resources>
```

The result is that the ?attr/actionBarSizeand ?attr/colorPrimary are reported as undefined.
(I am using Visual Studio 2022)

Comment: I tested the code you provided for Android 12 and it works well. You can try other version of Android.

Comment: That is not an option I'm afraid. Only 8.1 is possible

Comment: Try to remove `android` tag from your styles.xml like this: `<item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
<item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/actionBarSize</item>`. And what's the original text of your error message?